# Cannot get django-debug-toolbar to work

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

I have been incorporating advice from various threads on `debug-toolbar` here, but somehow cannot get it working. Would appreciate some help please.

1. I am not developing locally. The server hosting the code is a WebFaction server and I am testing it from a browser on my local machine. `debug-toolbar` is installed on the server and I can see it in the server's `PYTHONPATH`.
2. IP address used is the tuple of (`request.HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, `request.REMOTE_ADDR`)
3. When I use these same debug-toolbar settings in a fresh Django test project on my local machine, it works.
4. One post mentioned that using show_toolbar and returning True voided all the IP address checks. I have tried that too (below) to no avail.
5. (Edit) This works from shell. I can run `python manage debugsqlshell`

`settings.py`:

```
DEBUG = True

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
)


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ....
    'debug_toolbar',   # last in list
)

# Debug toolbar settings
INTERNAL_IPS = ('x.x.x.x', 'y.y.y.y') 
# This is IP address from request.HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR and request.REMOTE_ADDR that I see when I put an assert 0 in the code.
# When I got desperate, I also tried adding'127.0.0.1', '10.0.2.2' to no avail


DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = (
    'debug_toolbar.panels.version.VersionDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.settings_vars.SettingsVarsDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeaderDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.request_vars.RequestVarsDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.template.TemplateDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.logger.LoggingPanel',
)

# One post mentioned that using show_toolbar and returning True voided all the IP address checks. Trying it
def show_toolbar(request):
    return True

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': False,
    'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': show_toolbar,
    'HIDE_DJANGO_SQL': False,
    'TAG': 'div',
}
```

`page.html`:
    
        ...

```
<body id="try">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"; charset="UTF-8">
    ...stuff...
</body>
```

Now, what am I not seeing here?

Comment: I hope in "...stuff..." is a div tag, as that's the setting you have debug toolbar attaching too. (See 'TAG' parameter in DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG).

Comment: @Dan LaManna: Yes the page has many divs. I just added it incase there was something wrong with the `body` tag. I have also tried without `TAG` setting, but there is no difference.

Comment: Are you sure all the static files from the toolbar are in a place that are served by your server?  This includes CSS and Javascript files that come with the toolbar.

Comment: @Alok that was the problem. The .js was not being loaded. Thanks a much! Could you please make your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your:
    `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"; charset="UTF-8">`
be this instead?
    `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" />`